# Prepare data for generalized linear regression

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I want to perform `glm` for the dataset `Titanic` in R. I did the following steps to prepare the data and run glm:

```
install.packages("reshape")
library(reshape)
data=(Titanic)
da=melt(Titanic)

m=dim(da)[1]
for (i in 1:m){
    if (da[i,5]!=0){
        for (k in 1:da[i,5]){
            da=rbind(da,da[i,])
        }
    }
}

one=rep(1, dim(da)[1])
x=as.matrix(cbind(one,da[,1:3]))
y=da[,4]

m1=glm(y~x,family=binomial)
```

I received the error message:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 8932 rows, data has 2233
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your main error is in the specification of the formula: its right hand side being x, this is not translated into the "the main terms for each column of x": it just turns your matrix x into one column (of length 8932) and tries to use that as a predictor.

The simplest way to do this kind of thing, is to ensure that all your columns of interest are in 1 data.frame. Fortunately, in your case, you already have this in da:

```
m1<-glm(Survived~Class+Sex+Age, data=da, family=binomial)
```

In addition, by default glm will add the intercept by itself, so you don't need to manually specify a column of ones (as I avoided in the above).